# Sentences about Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure, we take $f\in L^1$ and we set $\hat{f}(t)=\int f(x) e^{ixt} dx$, for each $x$    $\ \ \ (i^2=-1)$

Show that:

1. $\hat{f}$ is continuous
2. $\lim_{t\rightarrow \pm \infty}\hat{f}(t)=0$
3. $||\hat{f}||_{\infty}\leq ||\hat{f}||_{1}$

   1. Since $f\in L^1$ we have that $f$ is measurable and $\int |f| d\mu <+\infty$ which means that $f$ is integrable. From that it follows that $f$ is continuous. The exponential is also continuous, so the integral is continuous. That means that $\hat{f}$ is continuous. Is this correct??
   2. Do we change the order of the limit and the integral??
   3. $||\hat{f}||_{\infty}$ is the supremum, right?? $||\hat{f}||_1=\int|\hat{f}| d\mu$ but  how can show the inequality??

Comment: $f$ might not be continuous.

Comment: @John why?? Doesn't it stand that if the function is integrable then it is continuous??

Comment: Use dominated convergence theorem for the continuity of $\hat{f}$.

Comment: That's not true. For example take any step function.

Comment: @John I see... How could we show then that $\hat{f}$ is continuous??

Comment: For part two you need to be careful, as $|e^{ixt}|=1$ for all $t$, so it does not go to $0$ as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: @John Since it is given that $i^2=-1$ do we maybe write the exponential as followed?? $$e^{\frac{-xt}{i}}$$

Comment: For part 3, to be presice the $||\hat{f}||_\infty$ means essential supremum. Are you sure that in 3 you have $\hat{f}$ in the RHS?

Comment: Actually I have a proof at hand (It's in Rudin's real and complex analysis). For part (1), fix any $t$ and let $t_n \to t$. Then check directly that $\hat f(t_n) \to \hat f(t)$ (You need to use some convergence theorem and the fact that $f$ is $L^1$.

Comment: @J.A.L The dominated convergence theorem is the following: Let $f_n$ a sequence of measurable functions. We suppose that $(i)$ There is an integrable $g$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ for each $n$. $(ii)$ There is a $f$ such that $\lim f_n=f$. Then $f$ is integrable and $\int f=\lim \int f_n$. How can I use that to show that $\hat{f}$ is continuous??

Comment: @MaryStar As John noted it is enough to show that for every sequence $t_n\to t$, $\hat{f}(t_n)\to \hat{f}(t)$. (1): $|f(x)e^{ixt_n}| = |f(x)|$ and $|f|\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. So by dominated convergence $\lim_n \hat{f}(t_n) = \int f(x)\lim_n e^{ixt_n}\, dx = \hat{f}(t)$.